# ListView with multiple layouts crash on scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, adapter

I have a custom adapter to show a list of boring things. Now, I want add a last item with a Summary (Resumen).

I'm using two layouts and two viewholders and it kinda works
[image]

**The problem start when I scroll back to the first item**. When the "Resumen" item disappear (the last one), the activity crashes.

Let me show you the adapter code (the relevant lines)

```
public class AdapterListaDeudaCliente extends BaseAdapter
{
    final private int VIEW_TYPES = 2;
    final private int TIPO_FACTURA = 1;
    final private int TIPO_RESUMEN = 2;

    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return VIEW_TYPES; 
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) 
    {
        if(position%2==0)
            return TIPO_RESUMEN;
        else
            return TIPO_FACTURA;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
         int tipo = getItemViewType(position);
            switch(tipo)
            {
                case TIPO_FACTURA: convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_deuda_basico, null);
                                                 break;
                case TIPO_RESUMEN: convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_deuda_resumen, null);
                                                 break;
            }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And finally, the crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:4078)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2915)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2065)
    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3315)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1701)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1111)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1685)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4635)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:916)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I would suspect that is something obvious if this code don't work at all, but only crash when the Summary view disappear... I can't detect the fail.

Thanks!!

I changeg the adapter and the layouts. Each the layout is made of only one plain textView. The app crashes when I scroll the listView.

This is weird.

More info: I'm using API level 8 and the compatibility pack. The activity is a FragmentActivity and I'm using the listView inside a ViewPager.

Comment: usually it gives a little more in the crash log including the line of your code causing the issue, can you post the whole error log?

Comment: Ok... I'm adding the whole error log (the red lines)

Comment: still not seeing any references to your code, almost always have one, maybe a little more red logcat?

Comment: You are probably trying to recycle a view of the wrong type.

Comment: Let me try using the adapter without recycling... wait a minute...

Comment: I removed almost every line of code of the adapter (recycle, Holder, get and set data). The only code left is the inflate layout code. Could be this mean that the problem is with the layout xml?

Comment: Can you add the code where you are manipulating the 'data' and also the listview where you are setting the adapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is weird... but the problem is here:

```
final private int VIEW_TYPES = 2;
final private int TIPO_FACTURA = 1;
final private int TIPO_RESUMEN = 2;
```

I changed it to:

```
final private int VIEW_TYPES = 2;
final private int TIPO_FACTURA = 0;
final private int TIPO_RESUMEN = 1;
```

And now it works...

Personally I think it makes no sense... Why the view type should start from zero?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there some problem with the length of array and the no of items in the array.. that's causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to why you're getting the crash, but it sounds like what you really want is a footer. See [this example](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter). That way you can get rid of the switches and category code. Remember that you **must** call `addFooterView()` **before** you call `setAdapter()`.